# create scafolding generators like react/open-wc using node

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna

I am trying to create a project structure to my team like how it implemented by [open-wc](https://open-wc.org/guide/#quickstart) or [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)
just say npm init @open-wc and it asks couple of questions and creates the folder with specified configurations.

I didn't find good articles on google except exploring the github projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintainer of `open-wc` here :)

So to get an `npm init` script all you need to do is define a bin in your package.json.
This is what we use for `npm init @open-wc`:

```
  "name": "@open-wc/create",
  "bin": {
    "create-open-wc": "./dist/create.js"
  },
```

So then for the name you have 2 choices:

- `create-foo` will be available via `npm init foo`
- `@foo/create` will be available via `npm init @foo`

**The generators itself**

That's a rather sad story... we looked around but we didn't find anything that really fit our use case well. There is http://yeoman.io/ which we used initially but it's huge and it meant we had a bootup time of ~30-40 seconds before the menu appeared. We felt we needed to do something so now we roll our own solution.

It covers what we need now with a fraction of the size (especially by being very careful with dependencies) which reduced our bootup time to about ~5-10 seconds.
We thought about promoting it as a separate standalone project but truth be told we don't have the manpower for it. It's just 4 files you can find here https://github.com/open-wc/open-wc/tree/master/packages/create/src - beware as there is no docu and quite some rough edges.

Still, if you don't find a better solution feel free to join us and with some help, we could make it a separate product.